# How do I retrieve records in MongoDB with PyMongo based on Flask URL variables?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

**Problem Statement**

I am building an API that must retrieve documents from a mongodb database, and I need to define a route in the Flask app that allows me to use the Flask URL variable as a value in my mdb query.

I have tried the following:

```
@app.route("/infrastructure/<infrastructure_type>")
def get_infrastructure(infrastructure_type):
    infrastructure = db.infrastructure.find(jsonify(f'properties.type.primary: {infrastructure_type}'), projection = {"_id": False})
    return jsonify([resource for resource in infrastructure])
```

**Expected results**

I was expecting to be able to go to a route like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/infrastructure/mine` and see all of the documents whose primary type in the database is `mine` returned as JSON.

**Actual results**

I received a 500 Internal Server Error and the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/repos/rdcep/shotgun-api/app.py", line 23, in get_infrastructure
    infrastructure = db.infrastructure.find(jsonify(f'properties.type.primary: {infrastructure_type}'), projection = {"_id": False})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1523, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 144, in __init__
    validate_is_mapping("filter", spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 494, in validate_is_mapping
    raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or "
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

**Example data from Mongo, showing the way the properties are nested**

[image: Example data from Mongo]

**Question**

What do I need to do in order to get my query filter in a format that mongo will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Alexandre Mahdhaoui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15515206/alexandre-mahdhaoui) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004499/11991071), I needed to pass a `dict` as my filter argument, but for some reason my database required dot notation for access. This answer contains the complete solution:

```
@app.route("/infrastructure/<infrastructure_type>")
def get_infrastructure(infrastructure_type):
    infrastructure = db.infrastructure.find({'properties.type.primary': infrastructure_type}, projection = {"_id": False})
    return jsonify([resource for resource in infrastructure])
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you directly pass a `dict` as your filter argument instead of `jsonify(f'properties.type.primary: {infrastructure_type}')`

Example:

```
@app.route("/infrastructure/<infrastructure_type>")
def get_infrastructure(infrastructure_type):
    infrastructure = db.infrastructure.find({'properties': {'type': {'primary': infrastructure_type}}}, projection = {"_id": False})
    return jsonify([resource for resource in infrastructure])
```

Comment: This passes without error, but returns an empty array on the client. Any ideas from there?

Comment: Interestingly enough, your filter looks right to me but also returns nothing when I use it to filter in the Atlas GUI. In Atlas I can use dot notation to get the intended result though.

Comment: I figured it out! It did require that I pass a dict as per your instruction, but it for some reason only wanted to work with dot notation as such: `db.infrastructure.find({'properties.type.primary': infrastructure_type}, projection = {"_id": False})`